# How to add physics to an object in Unity 5

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having a problem with Physics! I have imported an object which a bridge from 3ds max to unity 5 ,but the problem is that whenever I want to walk through on it ,I just fall down. It's like there's nothing called BRIDGE! I know there must be a problem about Physics. But how to fix it ?!

[image]

Comment: This question is often asked by beginners who don't know how video games are made.  (Of great confusion is that Unity documentation mentions "mesh" colliders, which are totally irrelevant.)  The answer by Minzkraut below is the **absolutely fantastic, now canonical, answer** to this common question.  What a great answer!

Comment: Video games have complicated LOOKING objects which the ARTISTS make.
You import the COMPLICATED "shaped" object to a game engine. Then the PROGRAMMER adds COLLIDERS.
The SHAPE is usually COMPLICATED, but the COLLIDERS are EXTREMELY SIMPLE.
Making the model is like writing a novel. Making the colliders is like writing poetry.  It takes a lot of SKILL to put the colliders, for each object or character, in a video game.
You use either SPHERE or BOX colliders. Here you would simply use BOX colliders.  You might need say three to perform the walking surface and maybe the sides (if necessary).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When importing a model into Unity it does not have any Collider.

Even though using auto-generated "MeshColliders" is an option
I **highly recommend** **not to use them**.
You never need such highly detailed colliders in a game.
Instead, you have to

## Add the colliders manually

**Here is a little step by step guide**

This is the imported model (made with blender) without any collider whatsoever
[image]

#### First thing to do is add a new box collider to the components

as shown in this gif
[image]

#### The next thing to do is scaling the box collider

by either entering the values manually or using the drag/GUI version like I do in the gif below
[image]

*(you probably know that already but the mode can be changed to orthographic by licking the small cube in between the cones in the upper right)*

#### If necessary you can add as many "detail" collider as you want

by repeating the steps. Sometimes sphere or capsule colliders might fit better but keep in mind that they have a higher resolution!
In this case i added another box collider representing the upper part of the car:
[image]

### Thats all you need to make things collide with your object

[image]

Comment: In this case I do not believe that he should be using box colliders. However, you answer is still valid and very detailed. Good job!

Comment: @AndrewGriffin I have read your answer and agree that his mesh LOOKS quite complex. yet you never need all the complexity of the visuals. In this specific case, a box collider to walk on and some to block the "legs" of the bridge totally suffice IMO. If you enable the convex option as you mentioned the space in between the legs would be lost as well thus making it impossible to pass underneath the bridge btw.

Comment: HI Andrew, I'm really sorry but you're incredibly wrong. It's totally inconceivable you'd use a mesh collider for the bridge in question. You don't have to believe me - ask any working professional game engineer.

Comment: Hi @Minzkraut this is a ***FANTASTIC "CANONICAL" ANSWER***.  It is great.  I am going to add a huge bounty to reward you.  I've always been looking for a great post that explains this point to beginners. **AWESOME!**

Comment: @JoeBlow haha thanks, I actually had a lot of fun making this graphical answer. it was partly inspired by yours btw ;)

Comment: @Minzkraut Yes, you are correct that convex colliders would not work on this bridge. Mesh colliders should only be marked convex if they are convex shaped or small like the sword example from Mr. Blow... not convex shaped but small enough that it doesn't matter. It also does depend on your gameplay requirements. I know that Skyrim/Fallout type games do not use primitive colliders on such objects because they would not interact with the environment very well. They actually use a lower poly convex collision model.

Comment: @JoeBlow I guess it depends on the kind of game you are making. I suspect the kinds of games you have worked on are for low end devices or RTS? If so, that would make sense. It also depends on the context of the collision. We use primitive colliders for stuff like player hit detection. I would not use a sphere for a rock though. I am sorry if I have offended you with my answer.

Comment: @AndrewGriffin isn't that ehy we have sphere colliders?

Comment: Hi Andrew!  You absolutely have not "offended" me in the slightest.  I really think it would be better if you **asked other experts**.  What you say just above (about "RTS" games and "low end" (what is that?) devices) does not make a lot of sense. You use ordinary colliders for objects like that in all ordinary aaa fp games. **Yes** in some cases a new approach for certain things is a kind of low-poly collider which integrates in a different efficient way with the physics engine. Another cool thing is automatic generation of primitves. But that is utterly irrelevant to the OP's question.

Comment: Yeah I think this is getting off topic. The OP has their answer on how to add collision to their bridge using a mesh collider or composite primitives. By low-end devices, I mean something like mobile phones, or TVs. Low poly convex collision models are definitely not a "new approach"... I've used them for years.

Anyway, I do appreciate your input but I think that you may be too attached to primitives. There is definitely a time to use them. Our project successfully uses a combination of both. Knowing when to use what comes with time and experience.

Comment: hey @Minzkraut enjoy that small bounty!

Comment: @JoeBlow Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

Right now you only have a MeshFilter, MeshRenderer, and Animator component attached. You walk through it because the mesh is only being rendered. In order to add collision, add a [MeshCollider](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MeshCollider.html) component to it.

Joe offers another way to do it with box colliders. There is a bit to know about both methods:

- Box colliders will take more time to set up (rather than just adding a
  component) and will have less precision. They will have faster performance.
- Mesh colliders do not collide well with other mesh colliders.
  However, this is often not an issue. If a mesh collider has the
  "convex" checkbox checked then it will collide just fine with other
  mesh colliders. Small items and any convex-shaped meshes should have
  "convex" checked.

For something like your bridge.. it depends on your game. If you are doing a top-down game with limited mobility (no jumping) then box colliders may work for you. If you are making a first-person game then I would strongly suggest mesh colliders. If you decide to use box colliders then you must set them up carefully. Otherwise, physics may not match up with what the player sees!

Do not worry about performance at this time. Worry about it later *IF* it becomes an issue. With the physics upgrade in Unity 5, it probably won't be.

Comment: Almost certainly: absolutely do not do this, Andrew.  use a BOX COLLIDER (or, a few of them).

Comment: Joe, for his complex geometry I would suggest the use of a mesh collider. His mesh is too complex to adequately replicate with box colliders.

Comment: I can only say you're quite wrong on this Andrew, sorry!  On any game at all you've ever played with an object like that, it would have been represented by one flat box collider (for the surface you are walking on) and (only in rare cases, if necessary) one for each of the "sides".

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in my updated answer earlier, if it is something like an RTS then boxes will suffice. If he is doing some sort of 1st or 3rd person game where the player controls the camera.. you can expect A LOT of clipping with box colliders.

Comment: Hi, no that's quite wrong Andrew.  I can assure you that for an ordinary 3D game (fighting, first person, car racing, whatever) such as the OP is doing here, it should be box colliders.  Anyway cheers!