# Combining lots of small polygons to one (some) big poly(s)

Tags: algorithm, math, unity-game-engine, graphics, 2d

I am looking for algorithm to merge lots of relatively small 2d polygons to one or some big polygons. In case two small polygons are touching or overlapping, they should be merged to one polygon.

My big goal is to sufficiently decrease amount of points/lines required to describe collider. Resulting collider can include some polygons, btw.

Could you propose an algorithm or library to do this? (Finally I will implement solution in C# for Unity3d).

I want my big collider to be created programmatically and I want it's boundaries to repeat outer boundaries of small polygons exactly. Thats why this question is NOT a duplicate of "How to add physics to an object in Unity 5".

Comment: That is a very non-trivial process. You can look for search terms such as "vertex clustering" or "incremental decimation" besides "mesh simplification". The CGAL library is likely to implement some of the functionality, but extracting it to C# won't be trivial.

Comment: there is a SUPERB answer to this common question here: it's one of the best answers on the site.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/37810695/294884 please vote it up

Comment: No, it doesn't. Please read my addition in question message.

Comment: "I want my big collider to be created programmatically and I want it's boundaries to repeat outer boundaries of small polygons exactly" you can only do that if the outside is a square or a triangle.   I don't understand why you want to do this?  There's nothing wrong with having many small triangles, indeed it is more efficient

Comment: Because some algorithms, for example shadow/light calculation algorithm, uses these colliders. And there is actually great difference between calculation of 4k vertex or just 400 vertex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For constructing the union of 2D polygons you can use [Clipper library](http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php).

> The download package contains the library's full source code (written in Delphi, C++ and C#),`

Comment: It looks like exactly what I need. @JoeBlow I am looking for algorithm, not mandatory C# or Unity3d package implementation.