# Don't know how to use collider in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm having a weird problem. I just downloaded an object model from the internet which is a garbage can, and I inserted it into Unity.

It seems to ave no collider! I also added Box Collider but again it does not work too, and I can go through the object!

Here's the image of project and the object with its components. Can you please tell me what's going on?

[image]

Comment: DO NOT USE the items that are known as mesh "colliders" in Unity or any game engine.  it is a very confusing topic. (Mesh "colliders" are **totally unrelated** to game physics: the name is confusing.)  You very simply use a box collider, or maybe a sphere or capsule collider. There's nothing to it.  This question has been asked a million times.  There was recently a fantastic answer about this, i will dig it up...

Comment: Here's the fantastic answer on the topic: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37810695/294884

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add physics to an object in Unity 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800092/how-to-add-physics-to-an-object-in-unity-5)

Comment: Mesh Colliders are totally valid and actual colliders. There's very good use of those depending on requirements, but it's probably too expensive for a prop indeed. For the solution to your problem, see Jesus_Crie's answer: you need to have an actual Mesh attached to the GameObject, and this should be applied on the Mesh Collider's Mesh property (it's null now: take a look at your "Mesh" value, which is "None (Mesh)" on your collider).

Comment: It is utterly, utterly inconceivable you would use mesh collider in the example given.  It's simply: "wrong".  It reflects a total misunderstanding of PhysX and game engineering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hy,

The cube collider is useless.
Your mesh collider don't work because there is no mesh on your object.
The mesh must be on a child of this element.

Sorry for my bad english i'm french.